# Escaping quotes inside text when dumping Postgres Sql

Tags: sql, escaping, postgresql

Let's say my table is:

```
  id    text
+-----+----------+
  123 | foo bar
  321 | bar "baz"
```

Is there any way to escape those quotes around 'baz' when dumping?

My query is in the form:

```
SELECT text FROM aTable WHERE ...
```

And I would like the output to be:

```
foo bar
bar \"baz\"
```

rather than:

```
foo bar
bar baz
```

Comment: Have you tried the `ESCAPE` clause from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-copy.html)?

Comment: @dawebber I was trying to avoid COPY since I'm SELECT'ing from a JOIN, and there's no way to use copy on that, right?

Comment: yes you can. Use `COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO ... `. It was on the same [page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-copy.html) I quoted earlier, midway through the page

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to use [`replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT REPLACE(text, '"', E'\\"') FROM aTable WHERE ...
```

You'll need to escape your escape character to get a literal backslash (hence the doubled backslash) and use the "E" prefix on the replacement string to get the right [escape syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).

**UPDATE**: And thanks to a_horse_with_no_name's usual strictness (a good thing BTW), we have a solution that doesn't need the extra backslash or non-standard "E" prefix:

```
set standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT REPLACE(text, '"', '\"') FROM aTable WHERE ...
```

The [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) option tells PostgreSQL to use standard syntax for SQL strings:

> This controls whether ordinary string literals ('...') treat backslashes literally, as specified in the SQL standard.

This would also impact your [`\x5C` escape](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-BACKSLASH-TABLE):

> If the configuration parameter standard_conforming_strings is off, then PostgreSQL recognizes backslash escapes in both regular and escape string constants. This is for backward compatibility with the historical behavior, where backslash escapes were always recognized.

Comment: Using the backslash that way is deprecated. It is highly recommended to use `standard_conforming_strings = on` which will be the default in the next release if I'm not mistaken. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: What's the best way to get a `\` in a string that works in PostgreSQL 8 and 9 without producing any warnings and doesn't care about the `standard_conforming_strings` setting? A lot of people (including me) have to deal with both 8 and 9 and many (such as Heroku users) don't have full control over the PostgreSQL configuration.

Comment: @mu is too short: getting a single quote `'` into a string is easy: simply put two quotes into the string: `'Peter''s bike'`. That is unaffacted by the standard_conforming_strings. The same is true for a double quote: `'12" Inch'` standard_conforming_strings is **only** about using a  backslash in the literal

Comment: Thanks guys, that's exactly what I was looking for. By the way would it be ok to do the following to avoid the double backslash: `REPLACE(text, '"', E'\x5C"')`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: No, I'm talking about the "\" not the quotes (I forgot to close my backticks in the comment and it is too late to fix it); that single backtick is supposed to be `\\`. Sigh, looks like I'm having backslash problems in this comment now, how appropriate.

Comment: @mu is too short: The property can be changed by a regular user for the current session. So the best thing is probably to run `set standard_conforming_strings = on` after connecting to the database and use standard syntax from there on.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks. I'd agree that going with standards across the board is best; OTOH, trying to walk someone through configuring their database and their connection might be a little more involved than we need for a data dump.

Comment: @Marco: As long as everyone you're working with knows that `\x5C` is a backslash then that'll be okay.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for the usual education. I merged your comments into an update to the answer (for posterity's sake).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following incarnation of the `COPY` command:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO ... WITH FORMAT 'CSV', ESCAPE '<WHATEVER ESCAPE CHARACTER YOU WANT>'
```

as [described here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-copy.html).

You might not have to do anything, as in some cases your `QUOTE` option will be doubled automatically. Please consult examples for the referenced link. You can also use `VALUES` in addition to `SELECT`. No further data mangling should be necessary.

This is assuming you are using 7.3 or higher. The syntax is slightly different between 7.3 and 9.0, so please consult the appropriate docs.